# circuit.measure() throwing error

Tags: qiskit, measurement, quantum-circuit

I have circuit like this

[image: Circuit]

when I try

```
circ.measure([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])
```

It is showing the error

```
list index out of range
```

I have tried this method before and it used to work on other circuits. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your circuit defined as circ = QuantumCircuit(3, 3) ?

Comment: @MicheleAmoretti Yeah, my mistake. I didn't include classical register. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the classical bits needed to store the measurements to your circuit.

Another option is to use [`measure_all()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.measure_all.html) method which adds a new `ClassicalRegister` with the needed classical bits:

```
circ.measure_all()
```

Or, [`measure_active()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.measure_active.html) method which adds measurement to non-idle qubits only. Similar to `measure_all()`, it will add a `ClassicalRegister` but its size will equal to the number of non-idle qubits being measured.

```
circ.measure_active()
```

Comment: thank you. I made silly mistake of not including classical bits :')